# Active voice with "accompany"

Tags: passive-voice

See these 2 examples of "accompany" being used with active and passive voices:

> Active voice: "X accompanies Y"

> Passive voice: "Y is accompanied by X"

I have found examples of both usages in dictionaries. However, according to some dictionaries, the passive voice is recommended for "accompany". This seems to conflict with the general rule that in English it is preferable to use the active voice. So I don't know what to do.

Is it ok if I use "accompany" with an active voice or is it a bit awkward?

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of dictionaries recommending passive voice (as opposed to merely providing passive voice examples)? Cambridge Dictionary has 'The actor accompanies his song with standard religious gestures'.

Comment: A headache often accompanies a cold or fever.

Comment: "OFTEN PASSIVE" https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/accompany

Comment: 'OFTEN' means it is often found (by the dictionary writers, during their research) to be used in the passive voice. That does not mean that you must always use it that way.

Comment: Does it not imply that the passive voice is preferable? The "OFTEN PASSIVE" label is rarely added to verb definitions in McM.

Comment: I don't see any judgement about it being 'preferable'.

Comment: In a passive version of an active statement, the subject and object change places, A headache often accompanies a fever. A fever is often accompanied by a headache. Are you focusing on the headache or the fever?

Comment: So the criteria is not to use the passive voice with "accompany" but to use the one (active or passive) that places first what I am focusing on.

Comment: "In writing, always consider whether you should use the passive or active voice. It will depend on what you, the writer, want to convey: if you want to draw attention to the doer, use the passive voice; if your intent is to put the focus on the action, then you should go for the active voice." - https://www.britishcouncil.my/english/courses-adults/learning-tips/when-to-use-the-active-and-passive-voice-in-writing

Comment: In this case we don't have a doer and an action.

Comment: The rule with "accompany" is: What goes at the end of the sentence (be it active or passive) is the focus. Right?

Comment: in "X accompanies Y", 'X' is the doer, and 'accompany' is the action.